# Que código usar para inserir o resultado em um ImageView?

Tags: android

> Estou querendo criar uma linha do tempo onde apareçam as imagens de um álbum do facebook, não estou conseguindo que as imagens apareçam na minha activity. Gostaria de obter um código para usar onde aparece **Insert your code here**. Alguém conhece uma solução?

```
final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            accessToken,
            "/id",
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {                        

                    // Insert your code here
                }
            });

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "albums{photos{from}}");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Utilize a biblioteca do Picasso, esse post pode lhe ajudar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273783/android-picasso-library-how-to-add-authentication-headers

Comment: Consegui carregar uma imagem utilizando a biblioteca do Picasso, porém não consegui implementar o código utilizado nesse post que me enviou, deve ser por falta de conhecimento, pois sou iniciante nessa área.   Para o meu projeto preciso carregar várias imagens de uma pagina do facebook. Estou querendo carregar as imagens como acontece no Instagram, ao abrir a tela as imagens da pagina são carregadas. De qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Use a lib [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) ela é a recomendada pelo google:

Ela possui uma sintaxe simples

```
Glide.with(context).load("url").into(imageView);
```

Para adicionar a lib as suas dependências adicione ao gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Comment: Assim como a biblioteca do Picasso a do Glide funcionou bem ao carregar uma imagem, mas para o meu projeto preciso carregar várias imagens de uma pagina do facebook. Estou querendo carregar as imagens como acontece no Instagram, ao abrir a tela as imagens da pagina são carregadas. Obrigado pela ajuda